# Generate a page with php based on what user clicks

Tags: php

So I've made a database of guilds of a MMO.  People can go there and filter the gaming guilds based on numerous different options and displays it all in a nifty table.  Example:

```
Guild Name - Focus - Leaders
Guild 1    - PvP   - Bob
Guild 2    - PvE   - Fred
```

Now what I want to do is make it so the guild name is a link that takes a user to that guilds page.  But the page doesn't exist until that person clicks on the link, I create a temple called viewguild.php and if person clicks "Guild 1" it takes them to http://somesite.com/viewguild.php?name=guild1.  And I have this done! By using this code:

```
echo '<tr><td><a href="viewguild.php?id='.$guild2.'">'.$guild2.'</a></td>';
```

it creates the link just fine! But my problem is, I can't seem to get my php file, viewguild.php, to generate information based on the guild name the person clicked.

Comment: What page doesn't exist until click? if you already have the viewguild.php, you only have to write <a href="./viewguild.php?name=$name">$name</a> or I didn't understand the question.

Comment: Show the viewguild.php , so that we can give a solution

Comment: The page is created just fine, it's the content in the page I can't figure out how to generate BASED on what name was clicked

Comment: There's almost nothing in veiwguild.php because I really have no idea what to put, but I do have this: $_GET['id']; echo $id; but it doesn't do anything

Comment: first store $id = $_GET['id']; then "echo $id;"

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$_GET['id']` variable in viewguild.php to get the name of the Guild in the URL.

Comment: So just like this?    $_GET['id'];  echo $id; Sorry I'm new to pHp haha

Comment: You can just `echo $_GET['id'];`. Or you can assign it to another variable `$guildName = $_GET['id'];`.

Comment: If I could kiss you, I would.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_GET` like this:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
echo "<a href='./viewguild.php?name=$name'>link</a>";
```

when you call your page like `mypage.php?name=guild1`

Answer (score 0):

Use $_REQUEST or $_GET to get the id passed in the URL to display whatever you want.

For example if you have id 1,2,3 or 4 and want each one to display something different:

```
if($_REQUEST['id'] == 1) {
    //display the info for id 1
} else if($_REQUEST['id'] == 2) {
   //display info for id 2 
}
```

and so on of you can use a switch statement. But basically using $_REQUEST['id'] will get you the ID passed.